# Nullable parameter in Blazor component gives "Possible null reference assignment" warning

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, nullreferenceexception

I am using .NET 7 and I have these two Blazor components:

`Child.razor`:

```cs
@using System.Xml.Linq

<h3>Child</h3>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public Func<XElement, Task<bool>>? OnDraft { get; set; }
}
```

`Parent.razor`:

```cs
@using System.Xml.Linq

<h3>Parent</h3>

<Child OnDraft="@OnDraft" />

@code {
    public Func<XElement, Task<bool>>? OnDraft { get; set; }
}
```

However, in Visual Studio I get a warning on line 5 in `Parent.razor` saying `Possible null reference assignment`:

[image]

Why does this happen when the parameter and argument both have the same nullable type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround seems to be to change:

```cs
<Child OnDraft="@OnDraft" />
```

to:

```cs
<Child OnDraft="@(OnDraft!)" />
```

Now there is no more warning:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can explain it.

You're dealing here with Razor code, not pure C#.

When the Razor compiler builds out this code, the relevant assignment line looks like this:

```cs
__builder.AddAttribute(9, "OnDraft", (object)((global::System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Boolean>>)(
#nullable restore
#line 11 "C:\Users\shaun\Documents\GitHub\Blazr\Blazr.Components\src\Components\SO76757934\SO76757934\Pages\Index.razor"
 this.OnDraft

#line default
#line hidden
#nullable disable
)));
```

Note the nullable directives.  The expectation is that `OnDraft` is a `System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Boolean>>` with `nullable` enabled.

Hence the warning.  Why?  You'll need to ask the Razor team.